# checking mutiple file input in php

Tags: php

Guys have a problem don't know why this is not working, i have file input field which can upload multiple images.

this is my form

```
<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input name="images[]" type="file" multiple="multiple">
<input type="submit" name="test" value="test"/>
</form>
```

If i submitted the code without selecting any files, i need to display an error message.
Here is my php code

```
if(!empty($_FILES['images']['name'])){
foreach($_FILES['images']['name'] as $key =>$value){
//other code
}
}else{
echo 'No images have been selected';
}
```

but this won't work any idea why is that..?

Comment: have you checked this by !isset($_FILES['images']['name'])

Comment: sorry didn't get you sir. what should i do with this? how can i use this in my code? thanks

Comment: check this var_dump php manual link http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php

Comment: yes i checked !isset($_FILES['images']['name']) but no luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
$hasUpload = false;
if(isset($_FILES['images']['name'])){
    foreach($_FILES['images']['name'] as $key => $value){
        if(!empty($value)) {
            // some codes here
            $hasUpload = true;
        }
    }
}
if (!$hasUpload) {
    echo 'No images have been selected';
}
```

Comment: i have tried this before. But this is also not working my friend

Comment: What's the error message?Have you `var_dump($_FILES)` for checking the form data?

Comment: No any errors its just go inside to loop rather than displaying echo statement. yes i get this after using var_dump($_FILES) array(1) { ["images"]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" } ["type"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" } ["tmp_name"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" } ["error"]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(4) } ["size"]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(0) } } }

Comment: The dump doesn't consist with the form. Do your modify somewhere?

Comment: I didn't change anything @mikespook where should i put var_dump()?